# How do i convert Discord.IMessage to string, using getMessageAsync((ulong)id)?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm trying to use the last message sent in a discord channel as a string in a windows form app, but i cant seem to get the `IMessage` converted to `string`. I'm also having trouble getting the last sent message `ID`.

Using `GetMessagesAsync(10).First().ID` returns 3 digits instead of 18? Using the actual Message ID from discord works tho.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
try
{
    await Client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, Token);
    await Client.StartAsync();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect.");
    return;
}

Client.Ready += getMessage;

    private async Task getMessage()
    {
        ulong msgid = (ulong)Client.GetGuild(525039283917291520).GetTextChannel(532107460807491584).GetMessagesAsync(10).FirstOrDefault().Id;

        var channel = Client.GetChannel(532107460807491584) as SocketTextChannel;

        var msg = channel.GetMessageAsync(msgid); // id is 3 digits instead of 18? not sure why.
        Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE:  " + msg);
    }

    private Task Client_Log(LogMessage arg)
    {
        Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arg);
        });            
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` you `GetMessageAsync` method, as it is a `Task<IMessage>`. Each message content is then stored in the `Content` property. Additionally, you have previously already gotten the message object, there is no need to retrieve another instance of the same message.

Ideally, the ready handler should look something like this:

```
private async Task OnReadyAsync()
{
    // attempt to get the channel
    var channel = _client.GetChannel(_channelId);
    // pattern match to SocketMessageChannel, the standard type required for a channel to be a messageable one
    if (!(channel is ISocketMessageChannel msgChannel)) return;

    // await the GetMessageAsync task to get the result of this task
    var msg = await msgChannel.GetMessageAsync(_msgId);
    // print Content if msg exists
    if (msg != null) Console.WriteLine(msg.Content);
}
```

References:

- [IMessage](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.IMessage.html)
- [ISocketMessageChannel](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.ISocketMessageChannel.html)

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work thanks to the code from Still H. I just modified it to get the ID of the last message sent :) Here's the code for anyone looking at this later on;

```
private async Task clientReady()
    {
        Channel = Client.GetChannel(525085451598692364) as SocketTextChannel;

        if (!(Channel is ISocketMessageChannel msgChannel)) return;

        var msgId = (await Channel.GetMessagesAsync(1).FlattenAsync()).FirstOrDefault().Id;

        var msg = await msgChannel.GetMessageAsync(msgId);

        if (msg != null) Console.WriteLine(msg.Content + " ID: ");
    }
```

Comment: There is still no need to repeat the get message process. Simply do `var msg = (await msgChannel.GetMessagesAsync(1).FlattenAsync())?.FirstOrDefault();`